# IIS Session Lost on Publish Web

Tags: c#, session, visual-studio-2012, web, iis-7.5

Previously with my Web project in Visual Studio 2012 I was able to hit the 'Publish Web' button and as long as I did not make any changes to any .config or .cs files most of the time my session data would persist so I wouldn't have to log in again every time I make a small change to a .css or .html file.

After messing around with some settings in order to get debugging functioning with w3wp.exe now the session data is lost every single time I click Publish Web, even if I made absolutely no changes between publishes.

I don't know what I did to change this but I really need to be able to make changes to static files without having so sign in every single time. How do I stop the session from being killed?

Comment: can you trace your changes in version control?

Comment: @trailmax unfortunately I tried rolling back my workspace to before I made any changes and it did not restore the old behaviour.

Comment: Also check your Publish Profile in settings-> File Publish Options

Make sure you don't have "Remove additional files at destination" checked and Exclude files from the App_Data folder if you don't need them published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you're publishing. Even if you didn't make any changes knowingly, the app domain will unload if:

- `web.config` was copied again (contents don't matter)
- `bin` folder was modified (again, same dlls with newer timestamps are considered modification)

AFAIK, Publish always updates `web.config`. One thing I'm not sure is whether it updates `web.config` if you don't have any transforms (.debug.config or .release.config) or not.

There are couple of things you can try:

- Set `web.config`'s Build Action to "None". That'd prevent it being copied to output altogether.
- Define a new Build Configuration, say "Static Content". Using this Build Configuration, define a new publish profile, say "Static Content". Add these lines to your `.csproj` file

  ```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' "> 
    ... 
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath> 
     <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn> 
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>web.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment> 
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>bin</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment> 
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

  This would prevent these 2 folders from being deployed so your app domain won't unload and session won't be lost. And you can still use the other profile to do a full release when needed.
- In your Publish > Settings > File Publish Options, ensure you have "Delete all existing files..." option unchecked.

Hopefully, one or all of these workarounds will resolve your issue.

**Update:** Based on the comments, here's a simple `AfterBuild` Target that recursively copies only changed files to publish folder. Simply copy the following  code into your `.csproj` file and tweak the paths appropriately.

```
<!-- define static content to be copied over -->
<ItemGroup>
    <SourceFiles Include="CSS\**\*.css" />
    <SourceFiles Include="Scripts\**\*.js" />
 </ItemGroup>

<!-- The target that gets executed after build finishes and copies files recursively -->
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="C:\Publish\YourApp\%(RecursiveDir)"
        SkipUnchangedFiles="True"
    />
</Target>
```

Now when you build, you should see the static content getting published to your publish folder.

**Notes:**

- `%(RecursiveDir)` copies files recursively, which helps in rebuilding the folder tree. Helpful if you have nested folders such as `css\fonts` and `css\images`.
- [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task has several other attributes (such as `ContinueOnError`, `OverwriteReadOnlyFiles`) that you may want to tinker with.
- You can also use standard VS macros in the destination path (e.g. `$(SolutionRoot)`, `$(OutputDir)` etc.).

Comment: I tried the workarounds excluding the new Build Configuration one, I can't create a new configuration in my situation. I did a comparison of the publish folder before and after a publish and I noticed that web.config isn't changing. The only files changing are the <ProjectName>.dll and <ProjectName>.pdb. Is there a way to have these only publish when they are DIFFERENT rather than every time?

Comment: By "not changing" do you mean the file modified timestamp or content? The former would change always, latter depends on whether you changed anything or not. Anytime you do a build, DLLs get modified if any of the source file changes. The only way to ensure them not getting published is via exclusion. If you cannot create a new build config, then maybe you can add the exclusions to debug build configuration. If course, this means that anytime you have `.cs` changes, you'd have to fire a release build/publish.

Comment: Another alternative would be to copy the js/css/images files to Publish output folder as a "Post Build" event. You can do it via by specifying a Post build event on the project that does xcopy or by specifying a AfterBuild target in the csproj. Let me know if you need examples. This way, anytime you build, your static files will always get copied over. You don't have to fire publish and you can avoid the whole issue.

Comment: "By "not changing" do you mean the file modified timestamp or content?..." I mean the timestamp is different but the content is unchanged. So I don't know why it is being recreated each time.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio or MSBuild bothers to do a content check. It simply publishes the file since its so vital. In your case, I think a post build event or target is the best and simplest way to go. Let me know if you need examples.

Comment: Your solution involving copying over the static files as a post-build task works and is the most ideal solution for my request. Can you formalize the solution into an answer so I can accept it and reward you the bounty?

Comment: See my updated answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean asp.net session? If yes then it is restored each time when the application pool is restarted . It could be caused by:

- web config change
- bin folder content change
- IIS app pool recycle

Generally it is a wrong practice to rely on session data. You have to always check for the data existence and restore if not exit without forcing the user to log in.

But you can keep the session alive if you run it in SateServer or SqlServer mode:
[Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You are correct about the cause however your proposed workarounds aren't feasible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Setup a new site in IIS to hold all of your static files.  E.g.

-Make sure it uses a different Application Pool than your other site

NewSite/Css/*.css
NewSite/Scripts/*.js
NewSite/JQuery
NewSite/BootStrap

(don't actually create this structure, you can manage it with a new vs project)

etc

Give it a localhost host header (MachineName and Port) internal access only.

Now Create a new Project in the Solution with your existing project, move said files to it matching a structure like above.

Setup a new publish profile to deploy your css, scripts, etc etc to the New site you made http://{machinename}:port

Call the Profile something like Dev_PublishStatics or Prod_PublishStatics (w/e you want)

Now you can make changes to CSS/Scripts in Project 2 and publish them with resetting Site A

-Lastly
In your Main site, Create virtual directories that point to the directories for Css, Scripts etc etc in the site you made above.

--Notes
You can also move ASPX files etc etc to the new Site and map them via virtual directories too if you want, but the dlls would need to be in both sites Bin folders.  But it works, just remember that if you changed code you need to publish to both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2:

Change the app pool settings,

```
IIS Manager
-> Application Pools
->-> Select Site Application Pool
->->-> Advanced Settings on the actions menu
```

Now set Disable Recycle for Configuration Changes to True, this will prevent the site from resetting on configuration changes.  You will need to remember to reset it yourself when new code needs loaded.

I also recommend setting

```
Start Mode = Always Running
Disable Overlapped Recycle = true
```